# count number of files (based on file extension) in multiple folders

Tags: find

I think it's best described with an example

```
parent1 (located inside /home/myuser
  - folder1
    - test11.png
    - test11.txt
    - folder11
      - test111.png
    - folder12
      - test121.png
      - test122.png
  - folder2
    - test21.png
```

if I can my script

```
get-number-of-files-per-folder "parent" png
```

the output should be:

```
folder1: 4
folder2: 1
```

at the moment, I'm using this command but it seems it counts all the files and not just the file extension I listed.

```
find /home/myuser/parent -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "{} : $(find "{}" -iname "*png" -type f | wc -l)" file\(s\)' \;
```

How do I know it's wrong? because when I ran this

```
find /home/myuser/parent -iname '*jpg' -type f | wc -l
```

it says I have zero JPG files but the script above says I have xx files inside a folder.

Comment: You do realize that `-iname '*$png'` doesn't match `.png` files, right?

Comment: Linux don't have folders but directories.

Comment: You might pipe `find` into `wc` or `awk`

Comment: @SatōKatsura a mistake in copy/paste. I fixed it now.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch and I can name those directories to whatever I want like "i-love-to-use-folder-for-directory-names"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming GNU `find`, and assuming your filenames don't have embedded newlines:

```
find /path/to/parent1 -mindepth 2 -type f -iname '*.png' -printf '%P\n' | \
    sed 's#/.*##' | \
    sort | \
    uniq -c
```

Comment: Not quite OP's requested output—`uniq -c` puts the count before the item, but does contain all the OP's requested data.

Answer (score 3):

Simple shell script approach:

```shell
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 directory extension" >&2
    exit 1
fi
cd "$1" || exit 1
for d in *; do
    [ -d "$d" ] || continue
    printf "%s: %i\n" "$d" \
        "$(find "$d" -type f -name "*.$2" -printf '1\n' | wc -l)"
done
```

… that just uses shell to iterate through all the files/directories in your target directory (well, except for hidden ones starting with `.`). It ignores non-directories, and for directories prints out the name followed by the file count (obtained by using `find` and `wc`). The `find … -printf '1\n'` is so that find just prints `1` for each file it finds—not printing the file name avoids all issues with, e.g., newlines in file names. And we just need to count the lines, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

**find** + **awk** approach for your current folder structure `/home/myuser/parent1/<folder>`:

```
find /home/myuser/parent1 -type f -name "*.png" \
     | awk -F'/' '{ a[$5]++ }END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }'
```

- `$5` - points to a folder name at the needed level (adjust this if your folder structure is different; it should be two more than directory depth of the parent. (So for `/tmp/parent1` it'd be `$4`, and for `/home/myuser/Documents/parent1` it'd be `$6`).